# I need special relationships with models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a project for one photographer that has an **application called Categories**: there are 4 predetermined categories for all the photos and every photo belong to one category.

What I want is that the admin has a section called `Categories`. When you click on it, the admin must show the 4 predetermined categories and when you click on a specific category, there has to be the option of uploading photos.

I mean, the final structure of this section must be:

> **ADMIN** ----> **CATEGORIES** ------>
>
> 1. CATEGORY 1 -----> Upload photos which belongs to cat1
> 2. CATEGORY 2 -----> Upload photos which belongs to cat2
> 3. CATEGORY 3 -----> Upload photos which belongs to cat3
> 4. CATEGORY 4 -----> Upload photos which belongs to cat4

**And I have this code:**

```
class Category(models.Model):

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('CAT1', 'Category 1'),
        ('CAT2', 'Category 2'),
        ('CAT3', 'Category 3'),
        ('CAT4', 'Category 4'),
        )
    category = models.CharField(verbose_name='Category', max_length=3, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, help_text='Choose de category of the image upload')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s"%self.category

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Image'
        verbose_name_plural='Images'


class ImageCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Category')
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image', upload_to='images/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s"%self.category

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Image'
    verbose_name_plural='Images'
```

**And in the admin:**

```
class ImageCategoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=ImageCategory
    classes=('open',)
    inline_classes=('open',)
    extra=0

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ImageCategoryInline]

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you explain the promblem you are running into? Your approach should be worling...

Answer (score 0):

One thought:
Make each image a model with foreign key to category. Then use admin inline of the image and add it to the category admin class.

With this, you can have an unlimited amount of images in each category and add and delete them in admin.

In fact, this is what you already did! Is there a problem with this approach?